# Laravel sharing values from a form in views

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a project in Laravel, where I want 2 values, resulting after the post method from a form, to become global variables in all my views with special prefixes.

My code in the controller:

```
public function to_dashboard(UserLocationRequest $request)
{
    $my_company_id = $request->my_company_id;
    $my_branch_id = $request->my_branch_id;

    View::share('my_company_id', $my_company_id);
    View::share('my_branch_id', $my_branch_id);

    return Redirect('employee/dashboard');

}
```

After this code I have errors:
'Undefined variable: my_company_id'
'Undefined variable: my_branch_id'

How can I do that, to propagate these 2 values in all my views?
Or how to send these values to my route.php and become global variables with View::share after submitting the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I will do it is by using `session` in [Laravel 5](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session).

You put your values in session key `Session::put('key', 'value');` like:

```
Session::put('my_company_id', $my_company_id);
Session::put('my_branch_id', $my_branch_id);
```

Then you can fetch the values from anywhere in Laravel:

```
$my_company_id = Session::get('my_company_id');
$my_branch_id = Session::get('my_branch_id');
```

I hope this covers your request.

Comment: Thank you. Session::set in my controller  and Session::get in my view.

Comment: Happy to know, you are in deed welcome. good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with Session::set and Session::get:

```
    public function to_dashboard(UserLocationRequest $request)
    {
     $my_company_id = $request->my_company_id;
     $my_branch_id = $request->my_branch_id;

     Session::set('my_company_id', $my_company_id);
     Session::set('my_branch_id', $my_branch_id);

     return Redirect('employee/dashboard');
   }
```

In my view:

```
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">My Company: {{ App\MyCompany::find(Session::get('my_company_id'))->name }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Branch: {{  App\MyBranch::find(Session::get('my_branch_id'))->name   }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ URL::to('auth/reset') }}">{{ Lang::get("site/menu.reset_password") }}</a></li>
      </ul>
```